# adding more columns of data to a sql query

Tags: sql

how do I add more of the available columns of data in the table to this query? I want to add the `evnt_dat` and `evnt_desrp` columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
                                panel_descrp   
                            ,   cardno
                            ,   lname
                           ) rid 
    ,   panel_descrp   
    ,   cardno   
    ,   lname

FROM ev_log

where evnt_descrp = 'local grant' 
      and datepart(yyyy,EVNT_DAT) = datepart(yyyy,GETDATE()) 
      and DATEPART(mm,evnt_dat)   = DATEPART(mm,getdate()) -1
      and DATEPART(dd,evnt_dat)  >= 1 and DATEPART(dd,evnt_dat)<=2

    GROUP BY  
        panel_descrp   
    ,   cardno 
    ,   lname
```

Comment: did you try adding, before the `from`:  "`,evnt_dat ,evnt_desrp`"

Comment: I am not getting you...

Comment: i think this query was generated for OP (or already existed) and they simply don't know how to add more columns to the select

Comment: @gloomy.penguin: That simple? If it is, then this guy really needs to go through W3School's SQL tutorial...

Comment: I don't know... we'll just have to see.... lol... I don't know what else they could possibly mean.  I see `evnt_descrp` in the `where` but I don't know where the other column comes from.  They might need to add the table name with it (which is slightly more complicated)..........

Answer (score 0):

If you want them there, you have to include them in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
                                panel_descrp   
                            ,   cardno
                            ,   lname
                           ) rid 
    ,   panel_descrp   
    ,   cardno   
    ,   lname
    ,   evnt_dat
    ,   evnt_desrp

FROM ev_log

where evnt_descrp = 'local grant' 
      and datepart(yyyy,EVNT_DAT) = datepart(yyyy,GETDATE()) 
      and DATEPART(mm,evnt_dat)   = DATEPART(mm,getdate()) -1
      and DATEPART(dd,evnt_dat)  >= 1 and DATEPART(dd,evnt_dat)<=2

    GROUP BY  
        panel_descrp   
    ,   cardno 
    ,   lname
    ,   evnt_dat
    ,   evnt_desrp
;
```

Or, use some aggregate function on them, for example `MAX` (then you won't have to put them in the `GROUP BY` clause, but the meaning of the query may not be what you expect):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
                                panel_descrp   
                            ,   cardno
                            ,   lname
                           ) rid 
    ,   panel_descrp   
    ,   cardno   
    ,   lname
    ,   MAX(evnt_dat)
    ,   MAX(evnt_desrp)
FROM ev_log

where evnt_descrp = 'local grant' 
      and datepart(yyyy,EVNT_DAT) = datepart(yyyy,GETDATE()) 
      and DATEPART(mm,evnt_dat)   = DATEPART(mm,getdate()) -1
      and DATEPART(dd,evnt_dat)  >= 1 and DATEPART(dd,evnt_dat)<=2

    GROUP BY  
        panel_descrp   
    ,   cardno 
    ,   lname
;
```

Comment: using the MAX function provides the desired query results, but if I add evnt_dat and evnt_descrp to the GROUP BY function to return/display those columns, it changes the results

Comment: @user2967024 You should either add them to the `GROUP BY` clause, or use the version of the query with `MAX` aggregate function. Do not use both, because of course you'll get different results - you will be aggregating on two more columns. You don't have to add those columns to `GROUP BY` to display them, you are already displaying them using the `MAX(event_dat)` and `MAX(event_desrp)`.

Comment: thanks Przemyslaw, you were right the evnt_dat and evnt_descrp columns are there.  Do you know how I would add a count by panel_descrp to the result?